# Knockout - display date format dd-MM-yyy but store the string as Date in viewmodel using jqm DateBox

Tags: knockout.js, datebox

I am new to knockout... I have the following problem.
I am using `jqm DateBox` to set Date and knockout plugin to manage the `viewmodel`. I want to display date in the format `dd-mm-yyyy` (AS IS) but in the same time i want that the `viewmodel` stores not the date as string but as a `Date()`. Is this possible? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I've done this for the jQuery UI Datepicker, im guessing its similar with Mobile.
From the init function of your custom datebox binding do

```
ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
    var observable = valueAccessor();
    observable($(element).datepicker("getDate"));
});
```

For e complete datepicker example see my collection of bindings
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bindings

Comment: Great, it works (i changed only the function datepicker with function of jqm datebox)

Comment: fwiw = $(element).databox("getTheDate")

Comment: theDate that was the worst name ever :D

Answer (score 0):

For info, this is the code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqmDateBox = {
    'init': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).data('datebox').theDate);
        });
    }
};
```